# Xcode 4.2.1: universal app runs on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.2

I am working on a universal application where I am stuck at one point. I was able to successfully launch my application both on iPhone and iPad but since 2-3 days, I am not able to launch my application on neither iPhone nor iPhone simulator but it runs smoothly on iPad/iPad simulator.

Also when I run my app choosing iPhone device it shows message like Running the App on iPhone simulator but I am not able to see any effect on my simulator. I am using Xcode 4.2.1 and I guess the issue is pertains to the same.

Comment: Is it crashing at delegate file?

Comment: No. Neither crashing nor showing the simulator. On right clicking the simulator icon, it shows iOS simulator but its not visible and in console also it is showing the message that app in running on iPhone simulator. Also if i try to run it on real device,only loading screen is visible.

Comment: right now the same prob is with old version of xcode?

Comment: Is there any away to resolve the issue? I really am confused and blank too..!!

Comment: Clean the project and try. Are you using some version control? If still the issue persists, try reverting to a revision some time back where you are sure the issue did not exist.

Comment: Please make sure that you have set expected iOS deployement target in projects setting and hardware version for iOS simulator.

Comment: no..i am not using any version control and can't go back :( Also i have already tried cleaning,restoring checking the deployment target and all the basic steps that were in my control. But in vain..!!

Comment: do u have tried to reset your simulator setting adn after that clean and install ur app in simulator......

Comment: @aakil : yes...hundreds of time..!! :((

Comment: i see a couple of people face same problem ,, and finally it seems there is a bug on the new xCode version with universal applications.

Comment: Yeah..I guess that is the case..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it is a solution or not but got a way out by reinstalling the `iOS Simulator`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem. This probably happens when you replace the application with the newScheme/EditScheme by mistake.

Just carefully check when you run your application is there your application name appear. This will be immediate left at where you choose iPhone simulator or iPad simulator version.