# App doesn't want to run on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I have an app that I want to run on my iPhone. I've code signed it and checked everything multiple times. It builds and then Xcode 4.3 just tells me "Finished running MYAPP on iPhone" -- but nothing happened . The app doesn't even install on my iPhone! Other apps I've made still work fine, even when built in Xcode 4.3.

Comment: Just for additional error logs: try to archive your app as IPA, then drag and drop the IPA to your connected device in XCode->Organizer. Do you get a "better" error message?

Comment: I had same issue. Check this.

Comment: @Sarah I think you forgot to include the link.

Comment: @Thomasw : oooops..sorry.. check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460621/xcode-4-2-1-issue-universal-app-runs-on-ipad-but-not-on-iphone

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are missing the armv6 architecture, while building on a armv6 device? Or you did setup required-device-capabilities, that aren't available on the device you are building on.

Try this: Build an archive, export an IPA file, open the Organizer. Drag'n'Drop the IPA onto your device. Here you will get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Ok Ill try that. Although I doubt it has anything to do with armv6 considering Im using an iPhone 4S